# is it possible to save NSMutableArray or NSDictionary data as file in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, nsdata

I want to save an `NSMutableArray` or `NSDictionary` as a permanent file. Then, I would like to reopen the file later.

Is this possible? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

To write in file

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:FILE_NAME];

[myArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

To read from file

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:FILE_NAME];

myArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

myArray will be nil if file is not present. And NSDictionary has similar methods. Please check the reference for the details of these methods.

Comment: @gef, is there any practical difference between TRUE/FALSE and YES/NO?

Comment: @taskinoor hi, how should be `FILE_NAME` be formatted? can you give me an example what file name can be used.

Comment: @Superman, FILE_NAME is any valid file name. There is no special formatting.

Comment: Because I tried your answer on my problem, doesnt seem to work. cant find it in the directory,

Comment: I am not being able to Find the path where the File is saved.. Help?

Comment: @Superman, as an example i'm saving an NSDictionary, and appending the file path "/Documents" with "loginDictionary.plist" was my solution. Hope that helps

Comment: also, @YugeshShrestha, what i just said might help, not sure. Good luck!

Comment: This is not working for me. I am saving an NSArray. The path I am presently saving is @"/Documents/newsfeed.plist"

Comment: Also my array is of a custom object, where the properties of the object in question are strings and numbers.

Comment: The files is never saved.

Comment: @KatedralPillon `@"/Documents/newsfeed.plist"` doesn't look like a valid path. You have to use `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`. However, this is a very old answer and I'm not sure whether things have changed in past few years. If you have items that can't be serialised then you probably have to serialise yourself. If you don't know how to do that then you can Google for a solution or ask a new question if Google isn't helpful.

Answer (score 2):

May be you can convert a Dictionary to JSON data.and write it to a file.

```
NSDictionary *dict = /* the NSDictionary/NSArray you need to write */

NSError *writeError = nil;
NSData* data;
data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&writeError];

if (!writeError) {
    [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```