# Which file format should I use to save an array to a file?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, file-io, nsarray

I am using the solution found here: [Save NSArray to File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829631/is-it-possible-to-save-nsmutablearray-or-nsdictionary-data-as-file-in-ios) and I am just wondering what type of file format I should save my array as.  Can I just use `.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any format. iOS `writeToPath:` does not read the extension. You can even make up weird file names.

Take the codes from your reference question as example,

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:FILE_NAME];

[myArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

the `FILE_NAME` could be in any ASCII values.

Answer (score 1):

The `writeToFile` of an array object creates a [property list](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/ReadWritePlistData/ReadWritePlistData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH8-SW1) file. So, while you can use whatever extension you want, it's generally good style to use the `plist` extension.