# How to save NSArray to and retrieve NSArray from file

Tags: ios, iphone, filesystems, nsarray

I have been trying to implement the answers given at [is it possible to save NSMutableArray or NSDictionary data as file in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829631/is-it-possible-to-save-nsmutablearray-or-nsdictionary-data-as-file-in-ios) and they have not been working for me. Will someone please inform me of what I am doing wrong? My NSArray is of a custom object, say `Cat`. Cat itself is constituted of strings and numbers. Here is my code

```
-(void)saveArrayToFile:(NSArray *)response;
{
//    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
//    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
//    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:PERSISTENT_FILENAME];
//    
//    [response writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    if ([paths count] > 0)
    {
        // Path to save array data
        NSString  *arrayPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"array.out"];
        // Write array
        [response writeToFile:arrayPath atomically:YES];


    }else NSLog(@"NO paths");
}

-(NSArray *)getArrayFromFile
{
//    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
//    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
//    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:PERSISTENT_FILENAME];
//    return [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    if ([paths count] > 0)
    {
        // Path to save array data
        NSString  *arrayPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"array.out"];
        NSArray *arrayFromFile = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:arrayPath];
        return arrayFromFile;
    }else NSLog(@"No file to retrieve");
    return nil;
}
```

First I tried the commented code. Then I tried the other. The problem so far is that the file is not being saved.

Comment: What does an ` NSArray must be a valid property lists` mean? My array is a collection of custom objects. The object itself has strings and numbers.

Comment: Why do you think the provided code does not work? What happened when you ran it?

Comment: Property list objects are described in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/PropertyList.html

Comment: Nothing happens. Absolutely nothing, when I try to save. Rather: after saving when I try to read, the result is always nil. So after further research, I am guessing the problem is that my NSArray's content is not a so called "property list"

Answer (score 4):

When you save it [response writeToFile:arrayPath atomically:YES] return false. So it is not saved successfully. Try use

```
Bool result = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:response toFile:arrayPath];
NSArray *arrayFromFile = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:arrayPath];
```

In your cat file:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString* score;
@property(nonatomic, assign)BOOL bGenuine;
@property(nonatomic, assign)NSInteger errorCode;

@synthesize score,bGenuine,errorCode;

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:score forKey:@"score"];
    [encoder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:bGenuine] forKey:@"bGenuine"];
    [encoder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:errorCode] forKey:@"errorCode"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    score = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"score"];
    bGenuine = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"bGenuine"] boolValue];
    errorCode = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"errorCode"] integerValue];
    return self;
}
```

Comment: The first snippet is to replace your [response writeToFile:arrayPath atomically:YES] and NSArray *arrayFromFile = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:arrayPath] respectively. The second snippet is to add a new NSObject subclass called Cat. Then you can set your response array to be response = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cat1, cat2,nil]

Comment: I see. I cannot edit the Cat object; it is from server (Google Cloud Endpoint). It seems that the only way is to get the encoder and decoder into the class but besides creating and using a subclass of Cat is there any other way?

Comment: I don't know the structure of your Cat object,is it in JSON format? I think the object mapping is necessary if you want to get the information from your array.

Comment: No. It is generated by Google's proprietary engine. But at least with your help, I seem to reach the root cause of my problem. I will keep looking to see how to deal with Google endpoints in this regard. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> If the array’s contents are all property list objects (NSString, NSData, NSArray, or NSDictionary objects), the file written by this method can be used to initialize a new array with the class method arrayWithContentsOfFile: or the instance method initWithContentsOfFile:.

This might be the reason why you can't read the file if your array contains custom objects

Alternatively try to use `NSKeyedArchiver`